# Счетчик произведенной продукции, как изменить цифры[HTML]

Tags: html, счетчики

Имеется такой счетчик на сайте, он таймером продолжает считать произведенную продукцию, как увеличить эти показатели? если изменять данные вручную, он просто сбрасывает и продолжает отсчет с последней точки

```
<section class="bottominfo">
  <div> <img src="/templates/fes24/img/roll@2x.png"  width="57" height="44" class="roll">
    <div class="timer">
      <div id="back">
        <div id="upperHalfBack"> <img id="secondsUpRight11Back" src="/templates/fes24/img/timer/top/0.png" ><img id="secondsUpRight10Back" src="/templates/fes24/img/timer/top/0.png" /><img id="secondsUpRight9Back" src="/templates/fes24/img/timer/top/0.png" /><img id="secondsUpRight8Back" src="/templates/fes24/img/timer/top/0.png" /><img id="secondsUpRight7Back" src="/templates/fes24/img/timer/top/0.png" /><img id="secondsUpRight6Back" src="/templates/fes24/img/timer/top/0.png" /><img id="secondsUpRight5Back" src="/templates/fes24/img/timer/top/0.png" /><img id="secondsUpRight4Back" src="/templates/fes24/img/timer/top/0.png" /><img id="secondsUpRight3Back" src="/templates/fes24/img/timer/top/0.png" /><img id="secondsUpRightBack" src="/templates/fes24/img/timer/top/0.png" /> </div>
        <div id="lowerHalfBack"> <img id="secondsDownRight11Back" src="/templates/fes24/img/timer/bottom/0.png" ><img id="secondsDownRight10Back" src="/templates/fes24/img/timer/bottom/0.png" 0 /><img id="secondsDownRight9Back" src="/templates/fes24/img/timer/bottom/0.png" 0 /><img id="secondsDownRight8Back" src="/templates/fes24/img/timer/bottom/0.png" 0 /><img id="secondsDownRight7Back" src="/templates/fes24/img/timer/bottom/0.png" 0 /><img id="secondsDownRight6Back" src="/templates/fes24/img/timer/bottom/0.png" 0 /><img id="secondsDownRight5Back" src="/templates/fes24/img/timer/bottom/0.png" 0 /><img id="secondsDownRight4Back" src="/templates/fes24/img/timer/bottom/0.png" 0 /><img id="secondsDownRight3Back" src="/templates/fes24/img/timer/bottom/0.png" 0 /><img id="secondsDownRightBack" src="/templates/fes24/img/timer/bottom/0.png" 0 /> </div>
      </div>
      <div id="front">
        <div id="upperHalf"> <img id="secondsUpRight11" src="/templates/fes24/img/timer/top/0.png" ><img id="secondsUpRight10" src="/templates/fes24/img/timer/top/0.png" /><img id="secondsUpRight9" src="/templates/fes24/img/timer/top/0.png" /><img id="secondsUpRight8" src="/templates/fes24/img/timer/top/0.png" /><img id="secondsUpRight7" src="/templates/fes24/img/timer/top/0.png" /><img id="secondsUpRight6" src="/templates/fes24/img/timer/top/0.png" /><img id="secondsUpRight5" src="/templates/fes24/img/timer/top/0.png" /><img id="secondsUpRight4" src="/templates/fes24/img/timer/top/0.png" /><img id="secondsUpRight3" src="/templates/fes24/img/timer/top/0.png" /><img id="secondsUpRight" src="/templates/fes24/img/timer/top/0.png" /> </div>
        <div id="lowerHalf"> <img id="secondsDownRight11" src="/templates/fes24/img/timer/bottom/0.png" /><img id="secondsDownRight10" src="/templates/fes24/img/timer/bottom/0.png" 0 /><img id="secondsDownRight9" src="/templates/fes24/img/timer/bottom/0.png" 0 /><img id="secondsDownRight8" src="/templates/fes24/img/timer/bottom/0.png" 0 /><img id="secondsDownRight7" src="/templates/fes24/img/timer/bottom/0.png" 0 /><img id="secondsDownRight6" src="/templates/fes24/img/timer/bottom/0.png" 0 /><img id="secondsDownRight5" src="/templates/fes24/img/timer/bottom/0.png" 0 /><img id="secondsDownRight4" src="/templates/fes24/img/timer/bottom/0.png" 0 /><img id="secondsDownRight3" src="/templates/fes24/img/timer/bottom/0.png" 0 /><img id="secondsDownRight" src="/templates/fes24/img/timer/bottom/0.png" 0 /> </div>
      </div>
      <div class="timerm2">М<sup>2</sup></div>
    </div>
    <em>фотолюминесцентной пленки <br>
    уже произведено</em> </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Надо начать с того, что HTML в принципе не умеет считать) И найти JavaScript, который запускается счетчик.

Comment: http://fes-24.ru/templates/fes24/js/script.js, функция lengthtimer